# Replace Values in a column with the values from another dataframe with the same column name and length

Tags: python, pandas, replace

I have two identical dataframes with the same column names, same length, I want to replace the values in one column from another column with the same column name

```
df1
Name total 
a     6
a     7
b     8
c     100
c     232

df2
Name total 
a     12
a     0
b     1002
c     2
c     1  

df1['total'] = df2['total']
df1.loc[df1.Name.isin(df2.Name), 'total'] = df2['total']

s = df2['total'] and tried with
s = df2.set_index('total')
df1['total'] = df1['total'].replace(s)
```

I keep getting NaN values in the column

my expected output is

```
df1
Name total 
a     12
a     0
b     1002
c     2
c     1
```

Comment: There are same Names? What is expected output? `df1['total'] = df2['total']` not working only?

Comment: Maybe help [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Also, you cannot reindex from a duplicate axis.

Comment: the two dataframes have 5 columns, they are all the same except for the 'total' column. I just wanted to update df1 with values from df2 for that specific column

Comment: So `df1['total'] = df2['total']` not working? If not, is possible explain why?

Comment: As per another comment: you should show the creation of the (example) dataframes as well; there's something that isn't shown here that is causing your problem.

Comment: Also, please show the actual result you got: which rows do you get NaNs, for example? And please show the dtypes of the dataframes, to verify you're assigned to similar types.

Answer (score 0):

`df1['total'] = df2['total']` just working fine. Try out the below code:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame([['a',6],['a',7],['b',8],['c',100],['c',232]], columns = ['Name', 'total'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([['a',12],['a',0],['b',1002],['c',2],['c',1]], columns = ['Name', 'total'])

df1['total'] = df2['total']
```

Hope this helps.